# CodeIgniter Advance URLs

Tags: codeigniter, url

In CodeIgniter I want URL like `www.example.com/deal/type/statename/cityname/town.html`, where `deal` can be some time deal or coupon, `type` can be restaurant or mart, `statename` can be any state name, and `cityname` can be any city name.

How can I do it?

Comment: Search for controller subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

This will be your route `$route['(deal|coupen)/(resturant|mart)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "YOURCONTROLLER/FUNCTION/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5";` where every first bracket represents $1, $2 .. $5 replace your controller and function with YOURCONTROLLER and FUNCTION before $1 as you didn't mention your controller and function put this line to your routes file application/config/routes.php [see more](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html)